# Create multiple tabhost elements in one view

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to create multiple tabhosts within a single view.  In this example I am using a sample of code from the iosched application and the 'workspace' view which allows users to swipe left/right to slide between views.

Each of the sliding views will contain a tabhost.

The problem I am having is that when I populate the second, third etc tabhost all of the content appears on the first tabhost, not the proper one.

I have a list of objects, each object in the list has a separate tabhost:

```
    Outer loop over each xxx to build a tabhost for each xxx

    // Setup views
    ctlr.mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.controllers_list_content_tabbed, null);

    ctlr.scrollView = (ObservableScrollView) ctlr.mRootView.findViewById(R.id.controllers_scroll);
    ctlr.scrollView.setOnScrollListener(this);

    ctlr.mTabHost = (TabHost) ctlr.mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    ctlr.mTabWidget = (TabWidget) ctlr.mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    ctlr.mTabHost.setup();
    ctlr.mTabRealContentView = ctlr.mRootView.findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
    int mTabReakContentViewId = ctlr.mTabRealContentView.getId();
    ctlr.mTabManager = new TabManager(this, ctlr.mTabHost, mTabReakContentViewId);
    .
    .
    . I loop several tabs like the snippet below and I expect each of these tabs on each tabhost
    .
    // Supply controller uri as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("controllerId", ctlr.mControllerId);

    String tagSpec = TAG_PROBES + "_" + ctlr.mControllerId.toString();
    ctlr.mTabManager.addTab(ctlr.mTabHost.newTabSpec(tagSpec)
                                            .setIndicator(buildIndicator(ctlr, R.string.db_maint_probes)),
                            DbMaintProbesFragment.class, 
                            args);

    .
    .
    .
    mWorkspace.addView(ctlr.mRootView);
    mCtlrs.add(ctlr);  <<-- this is the linked list of all the items added to the workspace
```

I think the problem is somehow related to the fact that each time the TabManager is new'ed in that last step it is always using the same RealTabContent reference.

Any thoughts??  This is driving me crazy.

While each tabhost is getting built in their respective fragments I can see that they are all referring to the very first RealTabContent id.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

What is TabManager? I cannot find it in the Android development documentation.

From what I can see, you are only creating one TabHost and one TabManager and adding tabs to that. Surely you want more than one?

I would use a ViewFlipper and add numerous linear layouts to it. I would then add the tab hosts to each of the linear layouts. This will create multiple 'screens' that you could hook up to be viewable when swiping left/right, each 'screen' housing its own set of tabs.

Comment: Sorry, TabManager is a helper class documented in Google sample code   http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html  It helps manage fragments on tabs.

Comment: That code snippet above is executed in a loop once for each tabhost I want created.